# How to filter collection with multiple conditions (strings and array of values) using lodash javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, collections, lodash

I'm trying to filter a collection with multiple conditions using lodash, it works fine with strings, but I want to filter by an array of id's for the part of the locations and string for status. I have tried to change the id to array of id's  `"location":{"id" :["1","4"]},` but it doesn't work

```
const collection = [ 
  {account: {id: "1", name: "a"}, location:{id: "1", name: "x"}, status: "ok"},
  {account: {id: "2", name: "b"}, location:{id: "2", name: "x"}, status: "ok"},
  {account: {id: "3", name: "c"}, location:{id: "4", name: "y"}, status: "failed"},
  {account: {id: "4", name: "d"}, location:{id: "4", name: "y"}, status: "ok"},]

 let filterByConditions = {
  "location":{"id" :"1"},
  "account":{ "id": "1"},
  "status": "ok",
};

let results = _.filter(collection, filterByConditions);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use the [filter](https://lodash.com/docs/#filter) method with the "matches" shorthand. This shorthand doesn't support an "or" condition; only exact matches. However, you can pass the `_.filter` method a *predicate* instead, and it'll work:

```
const collection = [ 
  {account: {id: "1", name: "a"}, location:{id: "1", name: "x"}, status: "ok"},
  {account: {id: "2", name: "b"}, location:{id: "2", name: "x"}, status: "ok"},
  {account: {id: "3", name: "c"}, location:{id: "4", name: "y"}, status: "failed"},
  {account: {id: "4", name: "d"}, location:{id: "4", name: "y"}, status: "ok"},]

let filterByPredicate = (elem) => {
  return elem.status === "ok" && 
    elem.location.id === "1" && 
    (elem.account.id === "1" || elem.account.id === "4");
};

let results = _.filter(collection, filterByPredicate);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This way could work for 1 or 2 elements in the array, but not for a longer with more elements.

Comment: If you want to make the "or" section more compact, you could instead do something like `["1", "4"].includes(elem.account.id)`. (Note that "includes" doesn't work in IE, you'd need to make your own function if you want to support legacy browsers.)